# Cannot access my webserver from outside the network

Tags: networking

I have set up a web server on port 3000 and set up port forwarding on the router to correctly forward all requests from port 80 to 3000 on my machine by stating the local ip of my machine. I have also disabled the firewall. Still when I try to hit the server using public IP of the network, the browser shows the address is unreachable. I am giving below the output of `route -n` command.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp13s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp13s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp13s0
```

I really can't figure out what error is causing this to happen. If you people need some more info, I would edit the question accordingly.

**EDIT**

I checked if my port 80 is open on canyouseeme.org. It shows it cannot see the service due to no route to host. Does it mean that the IP is blocking port 80?

Thank you!!

Comment: How did you get this public IP?

Comment: By searching for my ip on google

Comment: I am running a web server on 3000. I even tried changing to a non standard port by forwarding from 3000 to 3000. Correct me if I am getting this wrong

Comment: That doesn't tell you how many steps are between your router and whichever device that has this public IP.  For all you know your ISP may have another (or more) router between your router and the internet.

Comment: So for instance if I get public ip as 13.14.15.16. Then you wanto say that this ip not necessarily belongs to my home router. It may be possible that this ip belongs to a router that sits at ISP. Right??

Comment: So how do I achieve what I want to achieve. Making the web server on my machine universally accessible

Comment: If you don't have access to device that has the externally visible IP, there's nothing much you can do. First thing to do would be to check what IP your router gets by checking the router status page. If it's a different one from your google search result, then ask your ISP if you can be given an IP. If it's the same, then it's a router troubleshooting issue. At any rate, none of this has anything to do with Ubuntu. This is between you, your router and your ISP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106367/discussion-between-user13109153-and-muru).